# Single quotes inside double quotes are being coloured incorrectly for PHP

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Here is a php string:

```
", ',', '.')"
```

Coloured version of it looks like this on site:

[image]

It doesn't understand, that quotes can be nested and splits it as if it were 3 separate strings.

Here is the answer with such string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346937/789186

Is there any chance to fix?

Comment: Since all the syntax highlighting is handled by [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), you'd probably have to file a bug with them, unless SO is doing something weird that interacts with it. (Incidentally, their Github describes Prettify as working "passably" with PHP, so I'm guessing this is just one of those things that they aren't very concerned with.)

Comment: @ChrisHayes: I'd hardly call a bug like this "passable". So, after looking at the source of this code, there doesn't appear to be a problem with the syntax highlighter, but with the answer, instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That answer's syntax is incorrect. The user that posted the answer copied only a *part* of the string:

His code:

```php
a.totalsum LIKE REPLACE(' . $search . ", ',', '.')"
```

Should have been:

```php
'a.totalsum LIKE REPLACE(' . $search . ", ',', '.')"
```

Then the syntax highlighter works just fine.

---

In the example, I'll mark string starts with `+`, string characters with `_` and string endings with `-`:

```php
a.totalsum LIKE REPLACE(' . $search . ", ',', '.')"                                     '
//                      +________________- +__- +________where's the end?
```

Compared to the fixed version:

```php
   'a.totalsum LIKE REPLACE(' . $search . ", ',', '.')"
// +________________________-             +___________-
```

As you can see, the syntax was broken. The broken example also shows the comma and period after that aren't interpreted as part of the string, which matches your screenshot.